# How to build the requests handlers when the JInja template has multiple blocks?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, webapp2

I'd like to make a simple website running on the GAE framework/service. It's very small, and i don't really need the whole powerful Django framework, and thus i'm opting for the google-made Webapp2 framework, coupled with the Jinja2 templating langage.

I'm coming from a really bare-PHP-and-HTML-oriented background, so I have a hard time adjusting to the way a real framework works. My current greatest interrogation comes from how the templating system and the request handlers are working together, especially if the the page's template has several "dynamic" elements.

I'll first explain what I used to do in PHP, so you may better understand what i want to achieve.

Let's say I want a website with :

- a page title depending on the page being visited, eg : "Mysite.com | Control Panel"
- a dynamic menu bar, that may change depending on the user's profile or logged-in status
- obviously, a page body that completely depends on the page being viewed

The way i'd do it in PHP is thus here compressed into a simple example, `index.php`:

```
<?php

/*here use the $_GET or $_POST variable, and the $_SESSION variable 
to figure out who's connected, which page is being displayed,
and store those values in global variables, for the 
included modules to use */

include('page_header.php'); // renders the whole <head> </head> tag and its content

echo "<body>";
include('views/menu.php'); //generates the menu, displays it

switch($page_name){
    case "home":
        include('home.php'); //renders the page body for the homepage
        break;

    case "articles":
        include('home.php'); //renders the page body for the blog articles listing
        break;

    case "guestbook":
        include('home.php'); //renders the page body for the guestbook
        break;


}
echo "</body>";
```

Each included module, using variables from the script that called them (index.php), and the $_POST, $_GET, $_SESSIOn superglobals, figures out what to display, and renders it to HMTL. here `index.php` also does some kind of very basic routing, using the switch statement.

**Now,back to webapp2 and jinja2 framework**:

I understand that, to have a modular approach to build a web page with Jinja, you need to use block structures, and `extend` those blocks. Thus, to build a similar page to the previous PHP example, i made the following template `base.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/reset.css">
    {% block title %}
    {% endblock title %}
</head>
<body>
    <div class="menu">
        {% block menu %}
        {% endblock menu %}
    </div>
    <div class="body">
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock content %}
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What i don't understand, is how you you'll build the different Handlers that, in turn, generate the context that Jinja will use to render the blocks, and **avoiding redundency**.
**Also, can I use several different template files that, alone, extend only one block (eg: menu.html, header.html, body_home.html, body_articles.html, ...) **

You can use as a base to answer, [this example, from a small example that *almost* taught me all i needed to know](https://github.com/bitaVersion/cpfthw/blob/master/webapp2/views.py).

Thanks for any help provided, sorry for any grammatical errors, english's not my native tongue.

Comment: I've not programmed in php, but are you asking to `include` some common(somewhat static) content into `title` and `menu` or are they independent of in each handler?

Comment: `title.php`, `menu.php` may be using some of the global variables defined before they were executed, yes. Why this question?

Comment: It's confusing you are asking to build the different handlers that generate the context, but the link you provide is presicely doing that, it is a `jinja2` question or `webapp2` question.

Comment: It's kind of both, i'd just like to know the best practice to use to translate this basic PHP architexture  to webapp2+jinja2

Answer (score 1):

There's a feature in `jinja2` called [macros](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#macros) which is pretty much a parameterized include.

So if the includes should be parametized, you would do:

```
{% macro menu(params) -%}
   do something
{%- endmacro %}
```

And call the macro in your template:

```
<div> menu('bar') </dib>
```

If it is not necesary to provide parameters just leave it as static html in the parent template.

For the handler you can follow [App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/helloworld) hello world example, just use your link to guide you to load jinja's enviroment.

I know you want to translate the `php` example, but try to do as much logic as posible in your handler instead of the template.

To your second question, yes you can extend just one block if you want, and if you need the parents content there's a `{{super()}}` block to get them.

Comment: So, should i make a base handler that takes care of rendering the dynamic elements common to all pages (menu bar, footer, title bar), and then make all the page-specific handlers inherit from that handler? i understand the basic usage of jinja and webapp, i just can figure out how to prevent redundancy and keep modularity. If you know any example that fits my need, do share it with me :P

Comment: https://gist.github.com/60c844bee1428bf95d37.git, https://gist.github.com/3bab7f139269c1c28576.git, if you still have doubts comment on them, but prety much that's what is to it besides template inheritance and macros in the template part, and use different handlers for different pages.

Comment: to comment, should I commit? (i've never used gits before)

Comment: I don't think so, only a github account